# VS2010 debugger doesn't track variables correctly in the watch window, does VS2013 still have this bug?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, debugging, watch

Visual Studio 2010 debugger has issues with tracking watch variable memory locations. Sometimes it will mislead you badly because VS2010 is NOT showing you the variable you think it is showing you.

For example, if you re-use a variable name within a function, so which memory location should be displayed in the watch window CHANGES as the execution scope changes:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
   i=i+1; // do something, what isn't important
}

int i;
for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
  i=i+1; // do something 
}

printf("i=%d\n", i);
```

Now put the variable i in the watch window.

Obviously, which i (or value) is displayed in the watch window matters. If you run the program, you will see that as it enters the for-loop the watch tracks the i variable of the for loop. When it exits the for loop, and then hits the code below with the other variable with the same name the watch window isn't tracking that variable's memory.

You will see the watch window still declaring i is 10, even though in the 2nd loop i is now 0,1,2,... and after the 2nd loop i is actually 6, but the watch window still declares i is 10.

And what should the watch window do? I would argue, it should always show you the value of the variable with that watch name, that is in scope, as the language rules tell you only one of those variables is in scope at any given time.

Its a bug in the debugger's watch window functionality here (VS2010 seems to cheaply just find the first variable in the function that matches the name you gave it in the watch, and doggedly watch THAT memory space, regardless of what else may be in the code, even if a new variable with the same name has taken over scope (at which point the watch window is now lying to you!)

While I'm on VS2010, and need to stay there, and MSFT won't address a bug in older versions, I'd like to know if the bug still exists in VS2013.  I may get to install VS2013 in parallel soon, but its worth pointing out to prevent others from being mislead by what the watch window claims the value of a variable is. (even worse, when you mouse over the in-scope variable name in the code in the debugger, that wrong value is displayed as the 'tool tip'.

Comment: @HansPassant Using block-scoped variables named `i` as index of two successive loops in the same function is not a WTF. Having two loops in the same function is not automatically a WTF. I don't mean to be harsh, but if you think that either of these is automatically a WTF, I would hate to read your code.

Comment: What is a "WTF" exactly?

The code sample provided is just the simplest code that can demonstrate the problem in question to confirm it exists.  The actual code used isn't this; this just reproduces the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the same problem several times on VS 2013 :(

You can always open the disassembly window and check there what is the program really incrementing. You should see if it is a stack address (most likely on debug mode) or a register.

You can dump the register value in the immediate window, or directly in the watch window. Same with a stack address. Just type what you see in the disassembly window. For example:

```
00DC4095  mov         eax,dword ptr [i]  
00DC4098  add         eax,1  
00DC409B  mov         dword ptr [i],eax
```

break at 00DC409B and dump eax.

Comment: Good to know that its unfortunately still an issue with VS2013.  Will  have to log a bug against VS2013 once I get it installed.

Whether the effort to fix this is worth the trouble for the times it occurs I don't know (metrics on occurrence would be needed).  But I'd think the debugger watch window can surely keep track of variables correctly.  Certainly once the loop is exited, that first i goes out of scope and should be indicated as such - at a minimum - if one cannot track two variables in and out of scope in a piece of code.